# Stucky dithering as custom CIKernel does not work

Tags: ios, core-image, dithering, cikernel

I'm trying to implement Stucky dithering (error diffusion) as a CIKernel but I am a bit lost. I don't find a way to debug the filter (I m new to CIKernel).
Here is what I have came up so far, but the kernel does not compile, plus, I wonder how I could store the spreaded error to the destination pixels.
Help welcome. Is there a tool/way to trace or debug the code?

```
   float mDiffCoef = [
        0,    0     0,    8/42, 4/42,
        2/42, 4/42, 8/42, 4/42, 2/42,
        1/42, 2/42, 4/42, 2/42, 1/42
    ];

    kernel vec4 dither(__sample image) {

        vec2 coord = samplerCoord(image);
        vec4 pixel = sample(image, coord);

        // decompress pixel into rgb
        float red   = pixel.r;

        float color = 0;
        if (red >= 127) color = 255;

        float err = red - color;

        // Spread the error according to the matrix
        for (int x = -2; x <= 2; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y <= 3; y++) {
                vec2 workingSpaceCoordinate = destCoord() + vec2(x,y);
                vec2 imageSpaceCoordinate = samplerTransform(image, workingSpaceCoordinate);
                vec3 color = sample(image, imageSpaceCoordinate).rgb;
                color += err * mDiffCoef[(2+x)+5*y];
            }
        }

        return vec4(color, 1.0);
    }
```

**[Updated code to remove syntax errors]:**

```
kernel vec4 dither(__sample image) {

    float mDiffCoef[3 * 5];
    int i = 0;
    mDiffCoef[i++] = 0.;
    mDiffCoef[i++] = 0.;
    mDiffCoef[i++] = 0.;
    mDiffCoef[i++] = 8./42.;
    mDiffCoef[i++] = 4./42.;
    mDiffCoef[i++] = 2./42.;
    mDiffCoef[i++] = 4./42.;
    mDiffCoef[i++] = 8./42.;
    mDiffCoef[i++] = 4./42.;
    mDiffCoef[i++] = 2./42.;
    mDiffCoef[i++] = 1./42.;
    mDiffCoef[i++] = 2./42.;
    mDiffCoef[i++] = 4./42.;
    mDiffCoef[i++] = 2./42.;
    mDiffCoef[i++] = 1./42.;

    vec2 coord = samplerCoord(image);
    vec4 pixel = sample(image, coord);

    // decompress pixel into rgb
    float red   = pixel.r;

    float c = 0.;
    if (red >= 127.) c = 255.;

    float err = red - c;
    float color = 0.;

    // Spread the error according to the matrix
    for (int x = -2; x <= 2; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
            vec2 workingSpaceCoordinate = destCoord() + vec2(x,y);
            vec2 imageSpaceCoordinate = samplerTransform(image, workingSpaceCoordinate);

            float c = sample(image, imageSpaceCoordinate).r; //gb;
            color = c + err * mDiffCoef[(2+x)+5*y];
        }
    }


    color = clamp(color, 0., 255.);
    return vec4(255., color, color, 1.);
```

My main issue is how can I write the outpu pixel buffers by cumulating portion of value from the error diffusion?

Comment: Remember, Core Image filters - single, composite, kernel written - do not execute until called. Usually if I have a syntax error in a kernel I get a good explanation when I call it. What do you mean when you say "it doesn't build"?

Comment: I've moved your kernel code into a project of mine and am getting errors. I'll post an (rather lengthy) answer shortly.

Comment: You may find it easier to write your kernel in Metal Shading Language rather than GLSL — that way, you get proper syntax checking: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cikernel/2880194-init

Also, the colors in `image` are in the range 0...1 not 0...255 

Comment: ...one obvious error is that you have `color` declared as a float, but inside your loop, you're working with another `color` that is a `vec3`. The `return` is failing because it's using the float. Migrating to MSL makes finding these issues a breeze!

Comment: "You may find it easier to write your kernel in Metal Shading Language rather than GLSL " - 
it will return error on GPU family 1 devices. At least I have tested it on my iPad mini 3. So you will must have two versions - MSL and GLSL

Comment: Regarding MSL vs GLSL, ok. I will post a version that fixes compilation issues in a couple of minutes. My main issue is how can i write the outpu pixel buffers by cumulating portion of value from the error diffusion ?